# iOS Development: How can I return data from a modal view?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

If I have a parent view controller that displays a modal view with a textfield to collect data from the user, what's the best way to return that data to the parent view controller?  Currently, I assign the parent view controller as a delegate that's called from the modal view when the user enters the data.  Is there a simpler/better way to return data from a modal view?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would have the modal view dispatch an NSNotification that passes the data. A delegate works too, of course. I think that both a singleton and a delegate mean tighter coupling, but I understand that some might disagree.

But I do use singletons, too, if I need access to data stored centrally from many different places in an app. I just wouldn't use it simply to pass data from a view to another.

Comment: Agreed, singleton can be the right choice if you need to access the value from a variety of places. Otherwise a notification (or KVO observation) is great.

Answer (score 1):

When needing to store and pass data around I usually have a singleton class that I use throughout my app.  This keeps things a little cleaner in separating my views from each other.  Here's a simple implementation:

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/